# How to block all URLs in robots.txt except for the directory indexes?

Tags: robots.txt

For example, I want to block `/foo.php`, `/foo/foo.php` and every other similar URL in `robots.txt`, only leaving `/`, `/foo/`, etc. behind.

In other words, I want to block everything except the directories.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all URLs you want to block end in (or contain) `.php`, you could use

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.php
```

However, this uses the `*` wildcard, which maybe not *all* parsers support ([Google supports it](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)).

Comment: @think123: my previous suggestion was probably wrong → missing the wildcard `*`